# vuex mutations, edit or insert?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store, nuxt.js

I got this problem, im new with vuex, i am using nuxt with it, my problem is, i need to load data from a store state, for example.

i got this store:

```js
export const state = () =>({
    products:[
      {
        id:1,
        name:"onion",
        stock:1,
        price:12.00,
        created_at:"01/01/2020"
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name:"rice",
        stock:2,
        price:10.52,
        created_at:"02/01/2020"
      }
    ]
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

i need to load an item from products array in a form, my problem is that i need to know whatever the user needs to perform, insert a new product with the loaded data, or is just only  update it.

Comment: You can access state with `this.$store.state.products` from your components/pages

Comment: Just use id for that (assuming user is not able to edit it directly). When editing existing item, just pass an object from store (with id assigned). When creating new item, assign `id: 0`. In mutation/action check the id. If it's > 0, update existing item otherwise insert new and generate `id`